# Error escritura Fichero java

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy haciendo un metodo para crear un archivo , escribirlo , persistir el contenido en forma de byte array, de ahi recuperarlo y descargarlo.
Pero cuando me lo descarga el documento esta vacio sin los campos que seteo...(Los campos no estan vacios).
Aqui dejo el codigo a ver si alguien ve el error.

```js
File f = new File("name.txt");
  byte[] bytes = null;

  try {
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

   for (Class fit : listFit) {
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write("\n");
   }

   bytes = readFileToByteArray(f);

   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
   fos.write(bytes);
   fos.flush();
   fos.close();
   bw.close();

  } catch (IOException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
    }
    
    
     private static byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file) {
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  byte[] bArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
  try {
   fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   fis.read(bArray);
   fis.close();

  } catch (IOException ioExp) {
   ioExp.printStackTrace();
  }
  return bArray;
 }
```

Comment: Agrega como creas listFit por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código es correcto para crear y guardar el archivo y su contenido. Si tu archivo esta vacio se debe a 2 causas

- `listFit` no tiene elementos.
- `listFit` contiene elementos pero el método `fit.getHola()` no entrega ningún valor.

Podrías imprimir los valores para verificar si contienen o no valores.

```
System.out.println("Elementos contenidos: " + listFit.size());
...
...

for (Class fit : listFit) {
System.out.println("valor a insertar: " + fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write(fit.getHola());
    bw.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: Tanto la lista , como el metodo getHola() devuelven valores...